# What is web element for checkbox(text based HTML)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm writing some code but I cant find the locator of checkbox please anyone help me to find locator! I've posted an image and sample code I've written below.

[image: Img]

```java
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.id("term_and_conditions"));
target.click();
```

Comment: Do you get the target as null?

Comment: try `By.xpath(".//input[@name='term_and_conditions' and @type='checkbox']")`

Answer (score 0):

To click the *check box* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("label[for='term_and_conditions']"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[@for='term_and_conditions']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: @Ganesh Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: still not working same error display
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//label[@for='term_and_conditions']"}

Comment: you can check my code on

https://github.com/GaneshClass/Seleniumclass.git

Comment: @Ganesh Update the question with text based HTML

Comment: if im put current screen URL on driver.get then above locator ate working but when come from the pervious screen it displays XPath is unable to locate

Comment: @Ganesh I think the usecase related to _pervious screen_ is a new question altogether. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement please?